# Post to Facebook page from middle tier (PHP)

Tags: php, facebook, oauth, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to put together a prototype that would allow a company to manage remotely several Facebook Corporate Pages.

Imagine the following dataflow (for one Page):

1. module 1 runs on a cron job and retrieves posts/comments from a Page.
2. backend app lists posts and users reply
3. replies and posts are posted back to Facebook from module 2

My question is: 
Every module (including module 2) is behind company firewall and should be able to post to company's Facebook Page without having to register a Facebook App or being authenticated the usual way. Why? First of all, using current Facebook oAuth approach you have to include a redirect URL. I do not want to be redirected to anywhere else than to my intranet. Since Facebook does not "see" my intranet, the auth_token is not generated.

In conclusion, how to post to Facebook Corporate Page using that Page's admin user FBUID only to get auth_token?

Answer (score 1):

You're going to have to authenticate your app (and you do need an app) at least once. You can certainly ask for [`offline_access`](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/permissions/) so you don't need to have an active user session (and you'll need to, if you want to run your cron job successfully), but even `offline_access`-enabled tokens do go bad after a while (when a user changes their password, or uninstalls/reinstalls).

I'd recommend putting your cron server in front of the firewall and let users manage the rest behind the scenes, letting them use one auth token. You can obtain the proper token through `/me/accounts`, and you'll want to ask for `manage_pages` and `offline_access`. Once you get your auth token, simply store it until it expires (hopefully not for a really long time).